# Django, UpdateView deletes a row in the table

Tags: django, python-3.x

I complete remade a script, because I thought, an additional component is deleting a row in my database, which it doesn't. My script somehow manages to do it.

Here are the facts: the model is called "Settings", which is implemented as a singleton:

```
class Setting(SingletonModel):
    page = models.IntegerField()
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    addmonitored = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Add shows as monitored to Sonar")
    folders = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Subfolders for seasons")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Settings"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Settings"
```

The base Model looks like this:

```
class SingletonModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = 1
        super(SingletonModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        obj, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)
        return obj
```

The FormView looks like this:

```
class SettingsFormSetView(UpdateView):
    model = Setting
    exclude = ['page', 'xxxxxx']

    template_name = 'settings.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return Setting.objects.get(pk=1)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('settings')
```

I can open the form without any problems, enter the data, save it. I can reload the page and it still shows the data. If i reload it a few times, suddenly the form is empty and the row (pk=1, which is the only row in that table) is also deleted from the database.
No other stuff is interfering as far as i can tell. I am out of options, i cannot find the source for the problem.